# MODX getResources with Google maps infowindows

Tags: google-maps, modx

I am populating a Google Map with the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.414487, -0.207644),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    var onMarkerClick = function() {
      var marker = this;
      var latLng = marker.getPosition();
      infoWindow.setContent('<div class="map-info-window">\
                <h3>WEA [[+pagetitle]]</h3>\
                <p><strong>Branch contact:</strong> [[+branch-latlng]]</p>\
                <p><strong>Telephone no:</strong> [[+branch-phone:htmlent]]</p>\
                <p><strong>Email:</strong> [[+branch-email.htmlent]]</p>\
                [[+branch-more.htmlent]]\
              </div>' );

      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    };
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
      infoWindow.close();
    });

[[getResources? &debug=`0` &showHidden=`1` &parents=`[[*id]]` &depth=`4` &tpl=`newBranchMapMarkerTpl` &includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1` &tvPrefix=`` &limit=`0` &where=`{"template:=":9}`]]

[[getResources? &debug=`0` &showHidden=`1` &parents=`[[*id]]` &depth=`4` &tpl=`newMarkerInit` &includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1` &tvPrefix=`` &limit=`0` &where=`{"template:=":9}`]]
  });
</script>
```

And the contents of the 2 getResources calls are as follows:

newBranchMapMarkerTpl:

```
var marker[[+id]] = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng([[+branch-latlng]]),
                        title:"[[+pagetitle]]"
    });
```

newMarkerInit:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[[+id]], 'click', onMarkerClick);
```

but it does not grab the template variables as laid out in the setContent code; this is because it is only referenced once in the map page header, and normally would need to loop through each document. I've tried to create a new infowindow within the BranchMapMarkerTpl and it works but does not close the last infowindow when another is opened.

How could this be re-factored so it would pick up the template variable values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for template variables in a Template is `[[*tvname]]`. Try:

```
infoWindow.setContent('<div class="map-info-window">\
    <h3>WEA [[*pagetitle]]</h3>\
    <p><strong>Branch contact:</strong> [[*branch-latlng]]</p>\
    <p><strong>Telephone no:</strong> [[*branch-phone:htmlent]]</p>\
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> [[*branch-email:htmlent]]</p>\
    [[*branch-more:htmlent]]\
</div>' );
```

`[[+tvname]]` is correct as used within your getResources chunks, as the Template Variable values are being output to placeholders and not parsed via Template Variable tags.

Comment: I am such a dumbass. Yes you are absolutely correct about the syntax - unfortunately it still does not produce the values.

Comment: Is it those TVs I've indicated above that are blank when you 'view source'? Where exactly is the script code in your main post, in a template? Or a chunk? Very surprising if `[[*pagetitle]]` doesn't show up

Comment: Just noticed also that you have a further syntax error with the output modifiers, should be `[[*branch-more:htmlent]]` not `[[*branch-more.htmlent]]`. Same for branch-email.

Comment: Yes it is those TVs that are blank - it kind of makes sense that they are because of the way that MODX works, but I took this example from a Google Maps example and tried to MODXify it.The main script is in the head of the map page and the second 2 are obviously chunks for getResources.

Comment: I had the placeholders before as part of the getResources chunk and they showed correctly, but the infowindows did not function as explained above. I agree about [[*branch-more.htmlent]] but using a colon for some reason breaks the map.

Comment: So ultimately it is connecting the individual page TVs with the contents of the `infoWindow.setContent` code (called once, in the head) that is causing me the issue.

Comment: Forget about the map for a minute, and let's focus on getting the right output from the TVs. Because that's all rendered on the server and is set well before javascript comes into play. Remove `:htmlent` for now. Is `[[*pagetitle]]` showing a value? Are the `[[*branch-` TVs on the *current* resource, or are they actually attached to the resources you are looping through with getResources? If that's the case, we can try a different approach, let me know